# autoEscape is true but Ratpack doesn't escape HTML elements

Tags: groovy, ratpack

With Ratpack 1.6.1 I have a gtpl template with a div element as follows:

`div('<pre>HELLO</pre>')`

Ratpack doesn't escape the inner `pre` element even though `autoEscape` is `true`. Is there a way to fix/workaround the issue?

P.S. `autoEscape` in TemplateConfiguration is `true` by default. Setting it to `true` explicitly doesn't help too:

```
module(MarkupTemplateModule) { TemplateConfiguration config ->
    config.baseTemplateClass = MarkupTemplateExtensions
    config.autoEscape = true
}
```

Comment: please show more of your code. how do you set autoEscape..

Comment: @daggett autoEscape is true by default in TemplateConfiguration. Setting it to true explicitly doesn't help too. Please see the initial comment, I've updated it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the answer:

`autoEscape` doesn't enable escaping in templates. It only enables escaping data passed directly into `groovyMarkupTemplate` like that:

```
groovyMarkupTemplate('template.gtpl', var: '<pre>Escaped</pre>')
```

## Solution

In order to enable escaping in all templates by default, it's necessary to subclass `BaseTemplate` like that:

**Apply our own template processor in Ratpack.groovy**

```
bindings {

   module(MarkupTemplateModule) { TemplateConfiguration config ->
       config.baseTemplateClass = MyMarkupTemplate
   }
}
```

**Subclass BaseTemplate and override methodMissing():**

```
@InheritConstructors
abstract class MyMarkupTemplate extends BaseTemplate {
    @Override
    Object methodMissing(String tagName, Object args) {

        if (args instanceof Object[]) {
            Object[] argsArray = (Object[])args

            // Traverse argsArray ans escape every instance of String
            // with XmlUtil.escapeXml()

            return super.methodMissing(tagName, argsArray)
        }

        super.methodMissing(tagName, args)
    }
}
```